# Why is the wrong username showing up on a CW answer after a user changes names?

Tags: bug, community-wiki, user-names, specific-answer

An [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/397075) to [Interesting examples of vacuous / void entities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/interesting-examples-of-vacuous-void-entities) was written, and only edited by, @JonasLinssen:

[image: Revision history of answer]

However, the answer shows up as having been written by @PrudiiArca:

[image: The answer, showing a differently named author]

The text "PrudiiArca" is a link to https://mathoverflow.net/users/129445, which is indeed @JonasLinssen's page.

Presumably this is because the user changed their name, which, as I understand it, is a totally normal and reasonable use of the software.  However, shouldn't the displayed name of the post's author also change?

The post [Failure to update changed username on (edited, community wiki) answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4465/failure-to-update-changed-username-on-edited-community-wiki-answer) describes related behaviour, but the [answer by @JohnOmielan](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4466) indicates that this behaviour should not be observable in posts made after 2011.  As you can see in the screenshots above, the answer in question was posted on July 8, 2021.

Comment: I don't think your reading of John Omielan's answer is quite right. See, for instance, the [comment by Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/old-usernames-stick-to-community-wiki-posts#comment285100_110197) under the Meta SE answer that John quotes, and also the more recent [answer by Laurel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323637) to the same Meta SE question. To summarize, any edit to the CW post should (hopefully!) update the displayed username.  (In this case, probably the two edits were made by Jonas to his answer before changing his username.)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, I don't find what you [propose](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/28356) written in @‍JohnOmielan's answer (which, as you point out, just refers to the other MetaSE answer), or in the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/285100) by @‍GraceNote that you link (which seems to link the change in name to multiple revisions, which are present here), but I agree that the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323637) by @‍Laurel seems to say it explicitly.  With that in mind, I would accept your comment as an answer, or would be happy to close as dupe.

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, but I wouldn't be opposed to closing this as a duplicate, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By my understanding, this bug was never fully fixed, although *some* change in the SE software circa 2011 rectified the displayed usernames on most community wiki posts at that time. For instance, the list of [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/47474?sort=newest) to the Meta SE thread on which John Omielan's [answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4465/failure-to-update-changed-username-on-edited-community-wiki-answer/4466#4466) is based shows that this bug has been reported several times since 2011.

The [simplest workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/old-usernames-stick-to-community-wiki-posts/323637#323637) that currently exists is to make any (small) edit to the community wiki post. This should update the displayed username to the one currently used by the author of that post. In the case of the answer in which you noticed this bug, perhaps the OP had updated their username only after both edits were made, instead of between the two edits; that would explain why the multiple revisions did not trigger an update to the displayed username.

Of course, the downside is that any edit bumps the thread to the front page, so it would be best to use this workaround judiciously.